# When do we put "of" after to be?

Tags: prepositions

There's a sentence on my book (Pre-intermediate and Intermediate Vocabulary in Use by McCarthy) which I don't understand.

> Her family is **of** great importance to her.

Why **of**? Why isn't it **the** instead?

Comment: Why on earth would it be **the** ?

Comment: See: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/47382/421933

Comment: @randomhead I mean, I've seen a sentence like "I'm the great Physician". And it's not about the superlative. It's like "The great Physician bla bla bla..." and someone asks "Who's the great Physician?" And someone says "I'm the great Physician".

Comment: I've read your link. Big thanks for that. But I still don't know why the doesn't work.

Comment: You are barking up the wrong tree. The adjective "great" is not relevant to the construction, only the noun "importance." The phrase is **to be of [abstract noun].**